# Run the program without error?

Tags: java, jar, activiti

When i run the below program it getting errors messages

```
public class SavioDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
        .createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration()
        .buildProcessEngine();

    }

}
```

Can any one suggest which all jar files i need to include and run it properly?

Comment: The user guide on activiti.org has a section titled "Include the Activiti jar and its dependencies"

Comment: Without mentioning what error messages, you are getting,  a person might guess what you might have got , but can't solve the problem.

Comment: SavioDriver.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ProcessEngine
location: class SavioDriver
  ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
  ^
SavioDriver.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ProcessEngineConfiguration
location: class SavioDriver
  ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
                                ^
2 errors
This is the error jar files missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
               .createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResourceDefault()
               .buildProcessEngine();
```

Try this you may not get any error, provided you have added all the required jar files in your classpath.

Comment: I want to know which all are the jar files and from where i get it?

Comment: Please follow the link mentioned by @Mathiewz. You have to download all those required jars.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.activiti.org/download.html, download the library and include the jar to your buildpath
look at http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#getting.started.including.libs to know which jar include exactly